# Modifying CoreData data when @AppStorage is changed

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, appstorage

I have a SwiftUI app that has some checkboxes to set some values to true or false using `@AppStorage`. I would like to remove modify some data from CoreData whenever those checkboxes are enabled or disabled.

How can I make my `PersistenceController` remove that data from CoreData depending on a certain checkbox being enabled/disabled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `didSet{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [onChange(of:perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/onchange(of:perform:)) to trigger a side effect as the result of a value changing. E.g.

```
 .onChange(of: playState) { [playState] newState in
       model.playStateDidChange(from: playState, to: newState)
 }
```